# The convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n+1)}{n+1}H_{n+1}$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and $H_n=1+1/2+\ldots+1/n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, harmonic-numbers, mobius-function

Here in Wikipedia we've the [identity for harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Identities_involving_harmonic_numbers) $$\sum_{k=1}^n H_k=(n+1)(H_{n+1}-1)$$
(I believe that if there are convergence in each summand you can experiment with different identities involving harmonic numbers following my approach, but I don't use any property of harmonic numbers, only previous identity) then we multiply by $\frac{\mu(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}$ for integers $n\geq 1$, and *we take the sum* $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n H_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n+1)}{n+1}H_{n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n+1)}{n+1}.$$
Notice that if we presume convergence then using the Prime Number Theorem $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n+1)}{n+1}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\right)-1=0-1=-1,$$ thus if we presume convergence for each summand ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N$) one can write $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n H_k=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n+1)}{n+1}H_{n+1}.$$

> **Question.** It's known or can you deduce the convergence for some of these summands $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n H_k=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n+1)}{n+1}H_{n+1}?$$ Since I would like to know if the series in the title of this post is convergent, you can work with such or well with the series in LHS. **Many thanks.**

My attempt was using absolute convergence and I've calculated with Wolfram Alpha some [partial sums](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+mu(n%2B1)%2F(n%2B1)Harmonic(n%2B1),+from+n%3D1+to+1000), change your $N$ instead my $1000$ in the code in the box.

Comment: I hope that my calculations were rights, thanks all user by the patience and attention.

Comment: I'm confident that PNT in a quantitative form with relative error $o(1/\log^2n)$ together with partial summation yields the convergence of $\sum\mu(n)H_n/n$.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution and attention @barto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)\log n}n=-1.$$

(Found as Exercise 16, chapter 6 in H. Montgomery and C. Vaughan, *Multiplicative Number Theory: I. Classical Theory*, Cambridge studies in advanced mathematics, 2006, which on its turn references to work of Landau.)

Using $H_n=\log n+\gamma+O(1/n)$ we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)H_n}n=-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)(H_n-\log n-\gamma)}n$$
and the latter series converges absolutely.

Comment: Many thanks for your great answer.